# Return Single Field from MongoDB Document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

**Problem**

Hello. I'm just doing a simple test project in Node.js and MongoDB and I'm having some trouble getting data from a document. I made a function to retrieve data from the database and put the function in a module. Please see my document format as well as my code below. I really don't know what the problem is.

**Document Format**

```
{
    "email" : "example@helpme.com",
    "name" : "John Smith",
}
```

**Function Code**

```
module.exports = {
    GetInfo: function(MongoClient, assert, baseValues, targetField) {
        var result = "";
        MongoClient.connect(db_link, function(err, db) {
            assert.equal(null, err);
            var doc = db.collection('userdata').find(baseValues);
            if (doc != null) {
                result = doc[targetField];
            } else { db.close(); }
        });
        return result;
    },
}
```

**Function Call**

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');
var name = GetInfo(MongoClient, assert, { "email":"example@helpme.com" }, "name");
console.log(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to get result outside callback function

try like that

**UPDATE 19/09/16**

**Function Code**

```
module.exports = {
    GetInfo: function(MongoClient, assert, baseValues, targetField, next) {
        MongoClient.connect(db_link, function(err, db) {

            assert.equal(null, err);
            var collection = db.collection('userdata');

            collection.findOne(baseValues, function(err, doc) {

                assert.equal(null, err);
                if (doc != null) {
                    var result = doc[targetField];
                    next(result); // err to callback missing
                } else {
                  db.close(); // callback missing
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#findOne

**Function Call**

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');
var name = GetInfo(MongoClient, assert, { "email":"example@helpme.com" }, "name", function(res) {

    console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: Still cann't get name by `var name = GetInfo(MongoClient, assert, { "email":"example@helpme.com" }, "name");`.You should try something like  promise or generator.

Answer (score 0):

Because database connect and query are async i/o operation, so when you are trying to connect to mongodb, the `return result;` has already been executed.

Here is a promise version,you can try:

Function Code

```
module.exports = {
  connect: function(MongoClient) {
    return new Promise(function(resovle, reject) {
      MongoClient.connect(db_link, function(err, db) {
        if(err)
          reject(err);
        else
          resovle(db);
      });
    });
  },
  findOne: function(db, baseValues) {
    return new Promise(function(resovle, reject) {
      db.collection('userdata').findOne(baseValues, function(err, doc) {
        if(err)
          reject(err);
        else
          resovle(doc);
      });
    });
  }
};
```

Function Call

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
connect(MongoClient)
  .then(function(db) {
    return findOne(db, { "email":"example@helpme.com" });
  })
  .then(function(doc) {
    if(doc) {
      console.log(doc.name);
    }
  })
  .catch(console.log);
```